# php-fpm is parsing .phps instead of showing code (hilighted)

Tags: nginx, php

At the moment we're running nginx + php-fpm but we have an issue showing .phps files.

If I add .phps to the location rule, then it will start downloading the source.

In apache your normally would do
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

How can I fix this in php-fpm?

This is what the config's  contains:

```
location ~ \.(txt|php|html)$ {
    include server_fpm;
}
```

server_fpm cotains

```
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_pass backend;
```

fastcgi_params contains

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

#Custom parameters

#Legacy apache forward FCGI params
fastcgi_param HTTP_X_REAL_IP $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param HTTP_X_NGINX_VERSION $nginx_version;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

fastcgi_connect_timeout         60;
fastcgi_send_timeout            180;
fastcgi_read_timeout            180;
fastcgi_buffer_size             128k;
fastcgi_buffers         4       256k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size       256k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size    256k;
fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;

fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
fastcgi_index index.php;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
location ~ \.phps$ {
    fastcgi_pass backend;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT    $document_root;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME      $uri;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /path/to/hightlight_source.php;
}
```

hightlight_source.php:

```
<?php highlight_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); ?>
```

Comment: Hmm, a dirty fix, but still plausible. So php-fpm doesn't understand .phps files to return hilighted code?

Comment: Yes. But the mod_php inside does the same thing as highlight_file() function. Likely, php_fpm authors just don't want to add this odd functionality.

Comment: It's actually considered a feature, you're not limited to one-line highlighters, you can design your own.

Answer (score 1):

```
location ~ \.phps$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass backend;
    fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT    $document_root;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME      $uri;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  /path/to/phps.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

and then phps.php (in a dir o+x / mod 664)

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php echo basename($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php highlight_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); ?>
</body>
</html>
```